# php: swiftmailer questions

Tags: php, swiftmailer

i've just installed swiftmailer for php and i'm having some questions:

1. there's issue with german umlauts - i'm getting wrong characters how do i need to encode the message body properly?
2. is there a property in swiftmailer for getting the server log (the dialog when sending mail for debugging)
3. how can i set the property if the mail is plain text or html?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> there's issue with german umlauts - i'm getting wrong characters how do i need to encode the message body properly?

You can set the character set [using the third parameter of `setBody` or `addPart`](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-charset).  You'll want to make sure that the passed string is already in that character set.

> is there a property in swiftmailer for getting the server log (the dialog when sending mail for debugging)

You should be able to do this by [enabling](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/logger-plugin-howto) one of the [logging plugins](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/logger-plugin).

> how can i set the property if the mail is plain text or html?

You can define the HTML-yness of a message by [passing the content type to `setBody` or `addPart`](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-body).

I highly recommend that you [browse through the comprehensive online documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction) for more information on these topics.

Comment: Hello @Charles … your links running into redirect errors.

Answer (score 7):

set plain text or html like this

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
->setFrom(...)
->setTo(....)
->setBody($message, 'text/html')
;
```

for plain text change to setBody($message, 'text/plain')

Alternatively set it with:

> $message->setContentType('text/html')

or

> $message->setContentType('text/plain')

To get umlauts working try this:

> $message->setContentType('text/plain;
>   charset=UTF-8')

change plain to html for html emails obviously

You can also set it globally with:

> Swift_Preferences::getInstance()->setCharset('UTF-8');

However this is default so it is strange you are having problems. Is the problem with the message body or subject? If it is with the subject try:

> $subject =
>   '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';